# Problema no Depurador do VBA

Tags: excel-vba, debug

Bom dia!

Quando estou depurando / debugando a linhas de código com o tecla "F8", dependendo da função que ele entra, ao invés de ir para a próxima linha, o comando executa até o final, como se tivesse apertado a tecla "F5".

Não está fazendo isso em apenas um código, mas em todas as macros que eu tenho.

Alguém consegue ajudas?

Comment: Oi Thiago! Como vai? Poderia dar um exemplo de um código em que isso está ocorrendo? Isso pode variar muito de caso a caso, mas, de modo geral, o depurador pula para o final ou para uma próxima instrução quando as condições que ele "pula" não são verdadeiras. Por exemplo, em uma cláusula "IF" com uma condição que retorna Falso, o depurador segue direto para o "End if" e executa a instrução seguinte.

Comment: Oi André, tudo bem? Segue um exemplo

"Sub Limpar()
    
    
    Sheets("Base1").Select
    ult = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    If ult > 1 Then
    
    Range("A2:BI" & ult).Select
    Selection.Delete
    
    End If
    
    Sheets("Base2").Select
    ult = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    If ult > 1 Then
    Range("A2:BR" & ult).Select
    Selection.Delete
    
    End If
    
End Sub"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá!

Eu testei o código enviado, primeiramente, com as abas da planilha com algumas células preenchidas. Nessa situação, o depurador percorreu todas as linhas.

Em seguida, eu testei o mesmo código sem preencher as células e aconteceu o que eu havia colocado no primeiro comentário: como esse código em específico apaga as células a partir da linha 2 até a última célula preenchida, se não há célula preenchida, a condição imposta em IF se torna falsa e o depurador pula diretamente para o End If.

Não é um problema do Excel, pelo contrário, é até mais fácil assim para identificar se as condições colocadas no código estão sendo executadas ou não.

Comment: Oi Andréa, muito brigado pela ajuda!
Verifiquei aqui o ocorrido, tá dando certo.